# UI stucks while calling doBindService

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

I have create a service which fetches  the location using `LocationManager` listener.

Now i am biding my activity with it to get the updates but my app runs for the first time and call `doBindService` my UI got stuck for a while.

i tried to put it inside a `Thread` but in that way it doesn't update my UI as `doBindService`  might be running a different thread.

I have an `IncomingHandler` which gets the messages and update my UI.

i don't what is wrong ?

`doBindService` Code

```
public void doBindService(){

    bindService(
            new Intent(MyActivity.this, 
                     LocationService.class),
            mConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE
    );
    mIsBound = true;
}
```

`IncomingHandler` Code

```
class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
             switch (msg.what) {
                 case LocationService.MSG_GET_LOCATION:

                     UserLocation userLoc = (UserLocation)msg.obj;
                     locationTxt.setText(userLoc.getUserLocation().trim());

                     locationTxt.startAnimation(fadeOutLoc);



                     break;


                 default:
                     super.handleMessage(msg);
             }
         }
     }
```

**Update**

i am trying to store current location information in my application every 10 sec. and this may cause my UI stuck. so can anyone suggest me how can i store my location data periodically in database and my UI wont get stuck.

Comment: Service `onCreate` etc is executed on the same UI thread. I guess you are blocking there.

Comment: yeah i am calling it inside `onCreate` how to get rid of it ?

Comment: I meant `onCreate`/`onBind`/`onStartCommand`/`on...` inside your `Service` are probably taking too long. Calling `doBindService` from your `Activity` `onCreate` is fine.

Comment: Ohh yes.. as i am calling `locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);` in there

Comment: and if i create `AsyncTask` and try to call inside that then i am getting `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` runtime error

Comment: `getSystemService` is ok as well. Waiting for a thread, sleeping, filesystem access, database access, network access. That are the types of things you should not do there since they can take quite long. You can try to use DDMS [method profiling](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#profiling) to find what is taking too long

Comment: ya m accessing data base and storing the location information in db periodically , but i have to do that as my application demands that , let me try to run a separate thread to store it in database

Comment: Well everytime it create a new Thread if i try to update location info in database , any other way you know ?